# Importing CSV file into Hadoop

Tags: csv, hadoop2

I am new with Hadoop, I have a file to import into hadoop via command line (I access the machine through SSH)

How can I import the file in hadoop?
How can I check afterward (command)?

Comment: Do you want to add csv file onto HDFS? what do you mean by import into hadoop?

Comment: I just want to add my data in hadoop, those data are in CSV files

Comment: try `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -put <location of csv file> <location of hdfs>` .... example `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -put /home/address.csv hdfs://192.168.123.123:9000/address.csv`

Answer (score 13):

2 steps to import csv file

1. move csv file to hadoop sanbox (/home/username) using winscp or cyberduck.
2. use -put command to move file from local location to hdfs.

   ```
       hdfs dfs -put /home/username/file.csv /user/data/file.csv
   ```

Answer (score 1):

There are three flags that we can use for load data from local machine into HDFS,

**-copyFromLocal**

We use this flag to copy data from the local file system to the Hadoop directory.

```
hdfs dfs –copyFromLocal /home/username/file.csv /user/data/file.csv
```

If the folder is not created as HDFS or root user we can create the folder:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/data
```

**-put**

As @Sam mentioned in the above answer we also use `-put` flag to copy data from the local file system to the Hadoop directory.

```
hdfs dfs -put /home/username/file.csv /user/data/file.csv
```

**-moveFromLocal**

we also use `-moveFromLocal` flag to copy data from the local file system to the Hadoop directory. But this will remove the file from the local directory

```
hdfs dfs -moveFromLocal /home/username/file.csv /user/data/file.csv
```