# Stock market hdfs file where to get

Tags: hadoop, google-play, hdfs, stock

I am working on my project on Hadoop map reduce with Hive implementation.
To do so, I need .hdfs file so as to upload it into Hive. I need stock market .hdfs file. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thank You.

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is no such thing as a "stock market HDFS file". I'm assuming you mean a file containing stock ticker information. If you try and find that on the net (check yahoo finance etc) and then upload it from local to HDFS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277239/importing-csv-file-into-hadoop

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I found it at yahoo website